# how to prevent update check after login?

Tags: apt, login

Every time I log in to ubuntu 20.04 in my virtual machine, it takes some time until the prompt comes out.
This is the output during the login. It takes a while after I enter password until the update messages and shell prompt come out.

```
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS ab21q-ubuntu-20 ttyAMA0

ab21q-ubuntu-20 login: ckim
Password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-77-generic aarch64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

 System information disabled due to load higher than 4.0

 * Super-optimized for small spaces - read how we shrank the memory
   footprint of MicroK8s to make it the smallest full K8s around.

   https://ubuntu.com/blog/microk8s-memory-optimisation

309 updates can be applied immediately.
199 of these updates are standard security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable


Last login: Sat Apr  2 00:36:22 KST 2022 on ttyAMA0
ckim@ab21q-ubuntu-20:~$
```

So I guess it took so much to check the updates. How can I prevent this update check?

Comment: I would suggest applying security fixes to your system, your pasted messages show you've not applied fixes since before [26-August-2021](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/).

Comment: You'll need to [disable](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-disable-unattended-upgrades-on-ubuntu/) the "unattended upgrades" daemon. Don't forget to install updates manually after that.

Comment: Hello. An up to date Ubuntu 20.04 is 20.04.4 you show you have 20.04.2

Comment: Hi all. thanks for the comments.  This virtual machine is for a development of app/driver so if I upgrade the kernel, I have to chage the cross-compile enviroment. that's why I didn't bother to upgrade ubuntu on the VM. Ok, I'll either upgrade the kernel and cross-compile environment, or disable the 'unattended upgrades' sooner or later. I think @mikewhatever can put an answer so I can choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to disable the "unattended upgrades" daemon. Run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

...and select No.

PS: Generally, I wouldn't recommed to desable autoupdate, unless there is a specific case, such as the one at hand

Use this answer responsibly, and only when neccesary.